# Purpose of else and finally in exception handling

Tags: python

Are the `else` and `finally` sections of exception handling redundant? For example, is there any difference between the following two code snippets?

```
try:
    foo = open("foo.txt")
except IOError:
    print("error")
else:
    print(foo.read())
finally:
    print("finished")
```

and

```
try:
    foo = open("foo.txt")
    print(foo.read())
except IOError:
    print("error")
print("finished")
```

More generally, can't the contents of `else` always be moved into the `try`, and can't the contents of `finally` just be moved outside the try/catch block? If so, what is the purpose of `else` and `finally`? Is it just to enhance readability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[What is the intended use of the optional "else" clause of the "try" statement in Python?](/q/855759/90527)", "[Why do we need the "finally" clause in Python?](/q/11551996/90527)"

Answer (score 76):

`finally` is executed regardless of whether the statements in the try block fail or succeed. `else` is executed only if the statements in the try block don't raise an exception.

Comment: wow, this was so much easier to understand, thank you Sire! :)

Comment: What is the use of finally then? We can get "__finally__" printed outside of this try-except block also. Not able to understand the difference it will create

Comment: @Gupta the finally will always be executed, whereas if you just add something outside the block it means if the exception causes your program to stop whatever is after the block will not be done.

Comment: finally will always execute, even if you have a return statement in the "try" block. It will execute the code in "finally" before returning.

Answer (score 15):

If you move the contents of the `else` block inside the `try` block, you will also catch exceptions that might happen during the `else` block.  If the line

```
print(foo.read())
```

in your example throws an `IOError`, your first code snippet won't catch that error, while your second snippet will.  You try to keep `try` blocks as small as possible generally to really only catch the exceptions you want to catch.

The `finally` block gets always executed, no matter what.  If for example the `try` block contains a `return` statement, a `finally` block will still be executed, while any code beneath the whole `try`/`except` block won't.

Answer (score 14):

No matter what happens, the block in the `finally` **always** gets executed. Even if an exception wasn't handled or the exception handlers themselves generate new exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

```
try:
   print("I may raise an exception!")
except:
   print("I will be called only if exception occur!")
else:
   print("I will be called only if exception didn't occur!")
finally:
   print("I will be called always!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`finally` block always executed

`Else` block executed If there is not any exception.

I prefer to put the code in `finally` block which is always executed after `try` and except blocks.

I prefer to put the code in `else` block which is executed if the `try` clause does not raise an exception
same like this

**Finally**

```
try:
  f = open("file.txt")
  f.write("change file")
except:
  print("wrong")
finally:
  f.close()
```

**Else**

```
try:
   f = open("file.txt")
   f.write("change file")
except:
  print("wrong")
else:
  print("log => there is not any exception")
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible "states": `never occurred`, `handled` and `unhandled`.
You can map the control flow of the try-catch-else-finally clause into these 3 states like that:

```
from traceback import print_last

e_state = 'unhandled exception'
try:
    # cause an exception here [or don't]
except SomeException as e: # use a suitable [or not] exception type here
    e_state = 'handled exception'
    print('in "except"')
else:
    e_state = 'no exception'
    print('in "else"')
finally:
    print(f'in "finally". {e_state} occurred')
    if e_state == 'handled exception':
        print_last() # since the exception was caught - explicitly inform about it
```

Full examples below:

**1. Handled Exception**

```
from traceback import print_last

e_state = 'unhandled exception'
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    e_state = 'handled exception'
    print('in "except"')
else:
    e_state = 'no exception'
    print('in "else"')
finally:
    print(f'in "finally". {e_state} occurred')
    if e_state == 'handled exception':
        print_last()
```

Output:

> ```
> in "except"
> in "finally". handled exception occurred
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "...IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3251, in run_code
>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>   File ".../T/ipykernel_59815/1316012763.py", line 5, in <module>
>     1 / 0
> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> ```

**2. Unhandled Exception**

```
from traceback import print_last

e_state = 'unhandled exception'
try:
    1 / 0
except KeyError as e:
    e_state = 'handled exception'
    print('in "except"')
else:
    e_state = 'no exception'
    print('in "else"')
finally:
    print(f'in "finally". {e_state} occurred')
    if e_state == 'handled exception':
        print_last()
```

Output:

> ```
> in "finally". unhandled exception occurred
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [14], in <module>
>       3 e_state = 'unhandled exception'
>       4 try:
> ----> 5     1 / 0
>       6 except KeyError as e:
>       7     e_state = 'handled exception'
>
> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> ```

**3. No Exception**

```
from traceback import print_last

e_state = 'unhandled exception'
try:
    1 / 2
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    e_state = 'handled exception'
    print('in "except"')
else:
    e_state = 'no exception'
    print('in "else"')
finally:
    print(f'in "finally". {e_state} occurred')
    if e_state == 'handled exception':
        print_last()
```

Output:

> ```
> in "else"
> in "finally". no exception occurred
> ```

Comment: very good example indeed, but is there any real purpose for "else" - which can only be served with else

Comment: The same result could be achieved by placing your code at the end of the "Try" block, so.. no. But I'd say the "else" is the "official" block for that ("no exception occurred").