# Else statement in python

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner. Two quick questions on the code below:

1. Why can't I ever execute the `print("printed valueError")`?
2. Why does the else statement with `print("no error occurred")` will print no matters what I put in?

The code:

```
def int_checker(a,b):
try:
    if isinstance(a,int) and isinstance(b,int):
        print('both integers')
    else:
        raise ValueError
        print('printed ValueError')
except:
    print('error occurred')
else:
    print('no error occurred')
finally:
    print('no error occurred')

print(int_checker(1,2))
print(int_checker(1,'a')
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect as posted please correct it

Comment: `print('printedValueError')` is right after a `raise` statement. When the exception is raised, execution goes to the except block, not to the next line. So that line is unreachable.

Comment: As it is now, it is `finally` statement where `no error occured` is printed.

Comment: And `print('no error occurred')` is in a `finally` block. The point of a `finally` block is that it should *always* be executed regardless of what happens in your `try` block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "raise" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question -- when does the 2nd else statement get executed? Seems like it gets executed only when both inputs are integers. If one of the input is not an integer, we execute the except statement, and then jumps to finally
    else:
    print('no error occurred')

Answer (score 1):

**Why can't I ever execute the `print("printed valueError")`?**

It is simply because the code execution will `raise ValueError` exception and that jumps directly to the `except` part. To resolve, You can switch lines:

```
else:
    print('printed ValueError')
    raise ValueError
```

---

**Why does the else statement with `print("no error occurred")` will print no matters what I put in?**

You are using syntax with `try, catch, else, finally`. The order of those is:

1. Run code in `try` block.
2. Did some *error* occured?

   - **True:** execute code in `catch` block
   - **False:** execute code in `else` block
3. Run code in `finally` block. (This will happen always!)

From the above, the code form `finally` statement will be run everytime no matter if there was or wasn't error during execution. In most cases it is used e.g. when You `open` file in try block, read from it and suddenly an error occurs. In that case You want to `close` the file and clear the references. That code will go to the `finally` block.

---

Similar question on SO: [Purpose of else and finally in exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051934/purpose-of-else-and-finally-in-exception-handling)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question -- when does the 2nd else statement get executed? Seems like it gets executed only when both inputs are integers. If one of the input is not an integer, we execute the except statement, and then jumps to finally
    else:
    print('no error occurred')

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the "finally" block will print every time.

Try this: remove the 'else' from "try" block and add the following to the 'except' block:

```
print('printed ValueError')
raise ValueError
```

The 'else' after 'except' will only run if no errors occur